# How to display the value from textfield to column chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I want to display the value from text field to column chart, I downloaded the code for the chart in this website(https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/).
I used this code below but nothing happens. please help me!

```js
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var n1 = document.getElementById('FE');
var n2 = document.getElementById('SE');
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
 title:{
  text: "Average score per Evaluation"
 },
 axisY: {
  title: "FM performance score"
 },
 data: [{        
  type: "column",  
  dataPoints: [      
   { y: n1.value, label: "Faculty Self-Evaluation" },
   { y: n2.value, label: "Students' Evaluation" }
  ]
 }]
});
chart.render();
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <input name="FE" id="FE" type="text" value="4.06" >
 <input name="SE" id="SE" type="text" value="5.05" >

<div id="chartContainer"></div>
                        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any lucks? Is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value need to be passed as a float

Use this in your dataPoints object

```
dataPoints: [      
            { y: parseFloat(n1.value), label: "Faculty Self-Evaluation" },
            { y: parseFloat(n2.value), label: "Students' Evaluation" }
        ]
```